# Throughput vs. Latency Confusion

Tags: url, latency, throughput

According To This Article about Throughput and Latency H
"When You Go To Buy a Water Pipe, There Are Two Completely Independent Parameters That You Look At: The Diameter of the Pipe and Its Length"

But I Think These Two Parameters Are Related. Throughput Is Measured As Per Unit Time, So A Long Latency Will Affect Throughput, Say, If The Droplet Is Fast, More Of Them Will Pass The Pipe In One Second,

Can Any One Help Me Understand This?

**EDIT:**
the confusion is originated from counting queuing time as part of latency which we should not. Once a request is handled, the latency is independent of throughput.

Comment: School bus takes 50 passengers in one trip per hour.  So latency is 1 hour and throughput 50/hour.  Ferrari has much lower latency, say 20 minutes, but lower throughput, 2 people per trip, or 6/hour.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you another anology...Think of a car travelling on a single lane road from location A to location B..time taken by that car to travel from A to B is your latency...and the number of cars travelling at an interval, maintaining the latency is your throughput.
The factors that affect here is your medium of travel ie by road and no of lanes on the road.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about frequency. Say you have a window into the water pipe at some given point, and you send water droplets at some constant interval (say 1 droplet ever second). You count how often you see a single droplet pass by, and take the inverse (1/seconds). So if you count 1 second of elapsed time between droplets being observed, then you have a frequency of 1Hz.

Now say that you keep this frequency constant (1Hz), but you elongate the pipe. You send one droplet down and count how much time elapses before it reaches the end of the pipe. So say it takes 2 seconds for a single drop to travel from the beginning to the end of the pipe, then you have a latency of 2 seconds.

Now say that you widen the diameter of the pipe, and now you are able to send 2 droplets with a frequency of 1Hz. At the end of the pipe you will count 2 droplets coming out every second. So your throughput will be 2 droplets per second.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my bit in a language which I can understand**

When you go to buy a water pipe, there are two completely independent parameters that you look at: the diameter of the pipe and its length. The diameter determines the throughput of the pipe and the length determines the latency, i.e., the time it will take for a water droplet to travel across the pipe. Key point to note is that the length and diameter are independent, thus, so are are latency and throughput of a communication channel.

More formally, Throughput is defined as the amount of water entering or leaving the pipe every second and latency is the average time required to for a droplet to travel from one end of the pipe to the other.

**Let’s do some math:**

For simplicity, assume that our pipe is a 4inch x 4inch square and its length is 12inches. Now assume that each water droplet is a 0.1in x 0.1in x 0.1in cube. Thus, in one cross section of the pipe, I will be able to fit 1600 water droplets. Now assume that water droplets travel at a rate of 1 inch/second.

**Throughput**: Each set of droplets will move into the pipe in 0.1 seconds. Thus, 10 sets will move in 1 second, i.e., 16000 droplets will enter the pipe per second. Note that this is independent of the length of the pipe. Latency: At one inch/second, it will take 12 seconds for droplet A to get from one end of the pipe to the other regardless of pipe’s diameter. Hence the latency will be 12 seconds.